# How create a hash table for large data in python?

Tags: python, hash

I am working on a project where I'm reading as many as 250000 items or more in a list and converting each of it's entries as key to a hash table.

```
sample_key = open("sample_file.txt").readlines()
sample_counter = [0] * (len(sample_key))
sample_hash = {sample.replace('\n', ''):counter for sample, counter in zip(sample_key, sample_counter)}
```

This code works well when `len(sample_key)` is in the range 1000-2000. Beyound that it simply ignores processing any further data.

Any suggestions, how can I handle this large list data?

PS: Also, If there is an optimal way to perform this task(like reading directly as a hash key entry), then please suggest. I'm new to Python.

Comment: There's no code reason why that shouldn't work for longer lengths. Perhaps your program is running out of memory, if the items in question aren't small?

Comment: As far as I know python dictionarys work as hash tables

Comment: "Beyound that it simply ignores processing any further data." How? You computer saying "Nope, not gonna do it"? Do you get an exception, are no more values added to the dict, or can values put into the dict not be retrieved, or is it slower than expected?

Comment: @tobias_k I see that in the debugger!  No exception, no warning or error. So I said simply ignores. :)

Comment: @tobias_k the size of hash table. Which is only limited to 1000-2000.

Comment: Simplified version of your code: `with open(...) as f: sample_hash = dict.from_keys((line.rstrip('\n') for line in f), value=0)`

Comment: My guess is that some of the lines are the same, and your dict comprehension overwrites previously inserted keys. You are aware that keys in a dictionary are unique, right? Also, not quote sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think you might be interested in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @tobias_k I'm checking that. Double comfirming this is not happening. there is in any limit imposed by python itself on how large dictionary can be in size.

Comment: @tobias_k That was the issue. Thanks for that. Keys were repeating.

Comment: @tobias_k This is a irrelevant question. Just interested to know, what will be the time complexity in processing from a list to dictionary like I did above, any idea? How python does that in back end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your text file can have duplicates which will overwrite existing keys in your dictionary (the python name for a hash table).  You can create a unique set of your keys, and then use a dictionary comprehension to populate the dictionary.

**sample_file.txt**

```
a
b
c
c
```

**Python code**

```
with open("sample_file.txt") as f:
    keys = set(line.strip() for line in f.readlines())
my_dict = {key: 1 for key in keys if key}
>>> my_dict
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
```

Here is an implementation with 1 million random alpha characters of length 10. The timing is relatively trivial at under half a second.

```
import string
import numpy as np

letter_map = {n: letter for n, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
long_alpha_list = ["".join([letter_map[number] for number in row]) + "\n" 
                   for row in np.random.random_integers(1, 26, (1000000, 10))]
>>> long_alpha_list[:5]
['mfeeidurfc\n',
 'njbfzpunzi\n',
 'yrazcjnegf\n',
 'wpuxpaqhhs\n',
 'fpncybprrn\n']

>>> len(long_alpha_list)
1000000

# Write list to file.
with open('sample_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(long_alpha_list)

# Read them back into a dictionary per the method above.
with open("sample_file.txt") as f:
    keys = set(line.strip() for line in f.readlines())

>>> %%timeit -n 10
>>> my_dict = {key: 1 for key in keys if key}

10 loops, best of 3: 379 ms per loop
```